# Querying timestamp field of mongo oplog using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-oplog

I am trying to query timestamp field of mongo oplog collection using java.

Below is the code.

```
BSONTimestamp timestamp1 = new BSONTimestamp(1499172935, 1);

BasicDBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject("ts", new BasicDBObject("$gt", timestamp1) );

DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query1);
```

When I run above piece of code, it returns nothing.

Below is the converted query.

```
{ "ts" : { "$gt" : { "$ts" : 1499172935 , "$inc" : 1}} }
```

I executed the same query using robomongo and it also returns nothing.

```
db.getCollection('oplog.rs').find({ "ts" : { "$gt" : { "$ts" : 1499172935 , "$inc" : 1}} })
```

But when I changed the query to use Timestamp and executed it, it returns list of oplog records. Below is the working mongo query.

```
db.getCollection('oplog.rs').find({ "ts" : { "$gt" : Timestamp(1499172935 , 1)} })
```

How can I get the above query using java? 
or 
Is there any other way I can query oplog timestamp field using java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type 'BsonTimeStamp' to build your filter.

BsonTimestamp lastReadTimestamp = new BsonTimestamp(time, inc);

Bson filter = new Document("$gt", lastReadTimestamp);

dbCollection.find(new Document("ts", filter));